# Is there a easy way to embed Javascript code to a Jasper report which gets displayed in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper report which will be displayed in an iFrame of a web page.

For some reasons I need some JavaScript code embed in the report html page. Is there an easy way to do this without coding but configuration?

Comment: You can find solutions here: [Is it possible to embed javaScript in JasperReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531426/it-possible-embed-javascript-jasperreport) & [Embedding Javascript in the HTML component](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/542687/embedding-javascript-html-component) & [embed Javascript into html document](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537280/embed-javascript-html-document). [Generic Elements](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/genericelement/index.html#genericelements)